# Spring RestFul jquery jpa-criteria - HEAD returns 1 instead of 0

Tags: jquery, spring, criteria-api, restful-architecture

I have two entitys, foo and bar. One foo can have 0-n bar.

In foo and bar i have this data:

```
---- foo-table (2 rows) ---      ---- bar-table (1 row) ----
fooID                            barID     fk_foo
1                                1         1
2
```

Foo and bar are in restful service and i like to find the count of bar having the foo with id `2`.

Because fooID#2 has no referenced bar, the count should be 0. Here my problem: the service report me the count of bar referenced to foo#2 is `1` instead of `0`!

My controller:

```
@Autowired(required = false)
private final BarFilter[] filters = new BarFilter[0];

/**
 * Count all bars available.
 */
@RequestMapping(value="/bar", method = RequestMethod.HEAD)
public void countBar(final HttpServletResponse response, final HttpServletRequest request) {
    final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    final CriteriaQuery<Long> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Long.class);
    final Root<Bar> root = criteriaQuery.from(Bar.class);
    criteriaQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.count(root));
    for (final BarFilter filter: filters) {
        filter.count(request, criteriaQuery, root, criteriaBuilder);
    }
    final Query query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    final Number count = (Number)query.getSingleResult();
    LOG.info("Found " + count + "x Bar.");
    response.setIntHeader("count", count.intValue());
}
```

This is the count-method of the BarFilter implementation:

```
@Override
public void count(HttpServletRequest request, CriteriaQuery<Long> query, Root<Bar> root, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
    final Enumeration<String> parameterNames = request.getParameterNames();
    while (parameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {
        final String name = parameterNames.nextElement();
        String prop = name;
        if (!prop.contains("[]")) {
            prop = prop.replace("]", "");
            prop = prop.replace("[", ".");
            final String[] split = prop.split("\\.");
            Path<Object> path = null;
            try {
                final Root<Bar> r = query.from(Bar.class);
                for (final String property : split) {
                    if (path == null) {
                        path = r.get(property);
                    } else {
                        path = path.get(property);
                    }
                }
                query.where(builder.equal(path, request.getParameter(name)));
            } catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println(prop + " not found");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the jQuery-Request:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'rest/bar', 
        type: 'HEAD', 
        dataType: 'json', 
        data: {foo:{id:2}}, 
        success: function(data, state, xhr){
            alert(xhr.getResponseHeader('count'));
        },
        error: function(err) {
            alert('error:' + err.status);
        }
    });
```

Chrome gives me this request in network tab:
`http://localhost:8080/MyServer/rest/bar?foo%5Bid%5D=2` having this query-string:

[image]

And this response-headers:

[image]

Question: Why do i become a count of 1 instead of 0?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, after hours i got it.

I have two times a `.from(...)`, in the Restfull `countBar`-Method and another in the `count`-method. This creates a cross-join and reads the datas twice, only the second `where` becomes a where clause.